# CodeNameOne - NativeInterface - ClassNotFoundException on NativeLookup

Tags: java, codenameone, classnotfoundexception

I followed the instructions from this video https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html, but my code is throwing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: interfaces.MyNativeImpl on the look up line. The code I'm using is almost exactly that of the video.

```
package interfaces;

import com.codename1.system.NativeInterface;

public interface MyNative extends NativeInterface{
    public String sayHi();
}
```

in the android native directory

```
package interfaces;

public class MyNativeImpl {
    public String sayHi() {
        return "hi";
    }

    public boolean isSupported() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and in the java code:

```
    MyNative my = (MyNative)NativeLookup.create(MyNative.class);
    if(my != null && my.isSupported()){
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
```

Where did I go wrong now?

Answer (score 1):

That is perfectly fine code and will work on the device. 
You are seeing the exception in the simulator because the `native/internal_tmp` directory is missing from your runtime classpath but it shouldn't cause a problem other than no native interfaces on the desktop:

[image]