# Run tim error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.littlemonkey.connectivity.NativeConnectivityImpl

Tags: codenameone

My app generates an error message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.littlemonkey.connectivity.NativeConnectivityImpl. at runtime but not at the building process.

I have already imported the org.littlemonkey.connectivity.Connectivity.

Comment: How did you import the cn1lib? Are you using maven or ant? Is this on the simulator?

Comment: I have imported codenameone-connectivity in extensions. I am using ant. This is on the simulator.

Comment: This is a known problem with Ant there are several causes for this one of them is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878031/codenameone-nativeinterface-classnotfoundexception-on-nativelookup